# Creating a cycle between spaces on OS X

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, applescript

On Windows, I constantly used the keyboard shortcut 'alt-escape', which enabled me to move from one window to another without having to press x times 'alt-tab'. I'm new to mac OSX, and it seems that a similar shortcut does not exist, to my dismay.

My idea is to try and re-create the same kind of shortcut by switching between spaces. I found the shortcut that enables to navigate from space n to space n+1, but I find it very frustrating that it does not goes back to space 1 if space n+1 does not exist.

I have been thinking about writting an Applescript to perform such a task, and use Automator to create a shortcut to this script. However, I don't now if this would be fast enough, and I actually have no idea how to do such a thing. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a lot quicker to just use the direct shortcut to the required space.
It's literally quicker - the animation takes less time.

They set up as default key commands each time you enable a new Space, but they are not enabled by default, so you have to switch them on each time you add a new one.
System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts - Mission Control

[image]

Note that if you have a 10-key [num-pad] extended keyboard, by default the numbers are set to use those above the qwerty keys, not the 10-key, so you have to change them manually to use the 10-key.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. The problem is that with your solution, there is no simple key that I could just press continuously to move from one space to another ...

Comment: Correct, there is no built-in behaviour that will cycle from the last to first Space. You would need some fairly complex scripting to get the behaviour you desire - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768684/osx-lion-applescript-how-to-get-current-space-from-mission-control